# updating to macOS Catalina 10.15.4 - not working

Tags: macos, updates, macos-catalina

Just wondering if anyone has the same issue. Never happened to me, but I can't update macOS. I have 10.15.3 and the update notice on the desktop. I hit "update now" and the it asks me to reboot; I do it but after reboot I am still on 10.15.3 and the process begins over and over again.

Edited with picture from diskutility.

[image]

Comment: Please read this - [Ask Different question checklist](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3387/ask-different-question-checklist) - & see what additional information you can add. As it stands your question will need a 20-questions-style back & forth to even begin to diagnose what's happened.

Comment: Sorry. I understand the question was vague, but it was not intended as "looking for a fix" but rather as "is anyone experiencing the same thing?" while I was searching for a fix. Found it and will post is as answer.

Comment: Use the Console app to locate the installer log file, then see what the installer log says went wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, you're definitely short on space... :-D OK, you need to make some room on this drive, so if you've got an external hard drive (or several), copy whatever content you must to free AT LEAST 15GB of space on your Mac, then try to update again. Unplug your external drive(s) before you do that.

Answer (score 1):

Locate the  /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist file and cut-paste it somewhere else, on your Desktop for example, then reboot your Mac, and check for updates again.

EDIT: you'll need to enter your admin password to do that. If you encounter resistance, try this in Terminal:

sudo mv /System/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist /Users/Your-username/Desktop (Enter)

sudo

Comment: Thank you. I did that but the problem still persists. Something is preventing the update to be applied.

Comment: Sometimes, booting in Safe Mode is the solution: several system caches are cleared when you do that. You could also try Onyx or any other maintenance tool to do that while you're in a regular user session, but Safe Mode usually does the trick.

Comment: Thanks. Just tried rebooting to recovery mode, disabled SIP, rebooted and updated (rebooting again as it was required). About this mac reported 10.15.4. Then entered recovery mode again, enabled SIP, rebooted and ... about this mac reports 10.15.3. Something is really wrong but maybe its my system. Can't find the cause for this.

Comment: Is your Mac connected to a power source when you try to update? If so, can you check in Preferences under Security if File Vault is set to encrypt only when connected to the main, or not? If so, try to unplug the Mac from the power adapter and try Software Update again. File Vault has been known to create interference when updating system and apps alike, because it was working on the System directory and wouldn't release it for write.You can also suspend File Vault for a few hours and try to update, then resume it. It'll have to encrypt your volume from scratch, but hey...

Comment: Thanks. I have File Vault active, but I don't find the option to only encrypt when connected to main power source, only an "activate / deactivate" button.

Comment: How much free space do you have on both your system-reserved and MacintoshHD partitions? If macOS is going to download the whole update image, it's going to need space to store the .dmg file, and to expand it before writing it to your system partition. If you're short on space, this is going to be a problem, because a good chunk of the data will have to be written to disk, then properly installed upon reboot. Only a small part of it (kernel and a few dependencies) are stored in RAM during install. Can you post a screenshot of your Disk Utility window?

Comment: That may be it. I have posted the picture in the original question.

Comment: Yeah, you're definitely short on space... :-D OK, you need to make some room on this drive, so if you've got an external hard drive (or several), copy whatever content you must to free AT LEAST 15GB of space on your Mac, then try to update again. Unplug your external drive(s) before you do that.

Comment: Thanks. That was it. Oddly enough, macOS told me I only needed about 10GB. Still, those extra 5GB made the trick. Please make the comment into an answer for me to accept it.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to know it worked out for you!

Answer (score 0):

Trying to install it via system/preferences resulted in my mac rebooting with no update done, and no clear error message, so I have downloaded the installer pkg from Apple's site and tried a manual install. By trying to install the package the installer showed that I needed 1GB of extra space on my drive, so that was the problem: lack of available storage. IMHO Apple should throw an immediate warning to the user after failing to update trough system preferences (as it's the standard way of doing it).
EDIT: very strange. My system did appear as updated on 10.15.4 when going to apple logo / about this mac. But after one reboot, it gone back to initial state. This is not the solution.